# error while installing FirebaseInstanceID

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

i want to create a simple messaging app using Swift and Firebase.
but when i try to install the pods that i need i always get the same error about "FirebaseInstanceID"
i tried to uninstall, reinstall and update the cocoapods but with the same error
(im using VMware Workstation on my windows 10):

```
Dimensionss-Mac:messagingapp dimensionssolutions$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase (3.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.5.1)
Installing FirebaseAuth (3.0.6)
Installing FirebaseCore (3.4.4)
Installing FirebaseDatabase (3.1.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)

[!] Error installing FirebaseInstanceID
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/4x/vybryg713852s0_hg7_bxzrm0000gn/T/d20161107-18506-2i097m/file.tgz https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/18da95d517c54d0f/FirebaseInstanceID-1.0.8.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

Dimensionss-Mac:messagingapp dimensionssolutions$
```

and that's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'messagingapp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for messagingapp

    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  target 'messagingappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'messagingappUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the problem was in the VMWare settings. these steps fixed my problem:**

- 1 Select the virtual machine and select **VM** > **Settings**.
- 2 On the
  **Hardware** tab, select **Network Adapter**.
- 3 Select **Bridged: Connected
  directly to the physical network**.
- 4 If you use the virtual machine on
  a laptop or other mobile device, select **Replicate physical network
  connection state**. This setting causes the IP address to be renewed
  when you move from one wired or wireless network to another.
- 5 Click
  **OK** to save your changes.

https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-826323AD-D014-475D-8909-DFA73B5A3A57.html

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered a similar problem when I wanted to use AdMob.

I solved it by this method: replace **'pod install'** with **'pod update'**.

You can try it！

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'NativeAdvancedExample' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

[Problem screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaZlq.png)

[Resolve the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OINSY.png)

Comment: Actually i did it so many times, but the problem was in the VMware settings. Thank you for your answer. @Yuns Chou

Answer (score 0):

Your podfile looks kind of odd, try making it a bit simpler with this code:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'messagingapp' do

pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

This should work for you

Comment: im getting this error only when i try to install a "firebase/xxx" pod like Firebase/Database or Firebase/Auth or Firebase/Storage ....

Comment: by the way my podfile is the default one (using: pod init)
i only added the pods in it and changed the platform version

Comment: @dorydaniel try re-installing your cocoapods again, i know they recently made an update. just call "sudo gem install cocoapods" then try :)